# How do I get my text to flow with this <img> instead of waiting till it's clear? [HTML]

Tags: html, web

I'm trying to get the text to float around the little image on my web-page, and I've tried everything I can think of. I would embed the html and css here, but I had trouble doing it, sorry.

(I'll edit out the url when it's answered so I ain't using this as advertising.)
[removed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you've done it backwards.

Instead of having the image inline, and floating the `p`'s, float the image, leave the `p`'s inline. Make sure the image still comes *before* the text though...  Like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" style="float: left;">
<p>  
   this is some awesome text blah blah
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the image left, not the paragraph.